# Django Filter Query Solution

Tags: python, django, filter

I need to filter null and blank fields for several attributes. So far the solution I have found that works is this one :

```
avaluos=Avaluo.objects.filter(Q(Estatus='CONCLUIDO',Pagado=False,Factura__isnull=True)
|Q(Estatus='CONCLUIDO',Factura__isnull=True,Pagado__isnull=True)
|Q(Estatus='CONCLUIDO',Factura__exact='',Pagado__isnull=True)
|Q(Estatus= 'CONCLUIDO',Factura__exact='',Pagado=False))
```

However I am pretty sure this is not the best option.
Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you chain your clauses, it'll be more readable.

```
avaluos= ( Avaluo.objects
           .filter(Estatus='CONCLUIDO')
           .filter(Q(Factura='')|Q(Factura__isnull=True))
           .filter(Q(Pagado=False)|Q(Pagado__isnull=True)) )
```